.NET 8 Durable function - unable to catch activity timeout when running locally in VS 2022
I'm currently developing a durable function to handle large file uploads, and I'm having some issues trying to test activity timeouts locally.
In brief, the scenario I'm trying to test is as follows: orchestrator passes info required to handle the upload to an activity (ResumeUpload), and should this activity's CallActivityAsync Task fail with a TaskFailedException caused by a timeout, then I'll know that the upload has not completed and that I shoult call it again to resume the upload.
To accomplish this, I've set "functionTimeout": "00:01:00" in my host.json, and altered ResumeUpload to wait indefinitely using Task.Delay().
This works fine until the timeout occurs, at which point I would expect VS to stop at the breakpoint in the orchestrator catching the TaskFailedException; instead dotnet.exe just dies and the debug session ends.
Orchestrator and activity (simplified):
[Function(nameof(RunOrchestrator))]
public static async Task RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(context.Name);
    var uploadRequest = context.GetInput<UploadRequest>();

    try
    {
        await context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(ResumeUpload), uploadRequest);
    }
    catch (TaskFailedException ex)
    {
        // This is never reached!
        logger.LogError(ex, "inspect task failure exception");
    }
}

[Function(nameof(ResumeUpload))]
public static async Task ResumeUpload([ActivityTrigger] UploadRequest uploadRequest, FunctionContext context)
{
    // Force this activity to time out
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)); 
}

When the timeout occurs, I see a message saying this in the terminal that VS spawns when running the project, so far so good:
[2024-11-06T17:10:06.427Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Timeout value of 00:01:00 was exceeded by function: Functions.ResumeUpload.
[2024-11-06T17:10:08.451Z] A function timeout has occurred. Restarting worker process executing invocationId '9d808fd3-6274-4211-9dcf-d514e8fe3ec2'.

However the process dies immediately afterwards, and I'm dumped back into VS without ever reaching the breakpoint I placed in my orchestrator's catch statement. This is also true if I try catching a generic Exception instead of TaskFailedException.

I've scoured Google for hours and haven't encountered anyone reporting this issue, and in my searches I've encountered several examples that show that what I'm trying to do should be possible, for example:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/2697#issuecomment-1861737761
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-error-handling?tabs=csharp-isolated#custom-retry-handlers

I'm very green with regard to Azure Functions, so I may be missing something obvious, appreciate any help or tips you can think of! Thanks in advance.
EDIT:
I deployed the function to Azure and the orchestrator does indeed catch the TaskFailedException when the activity times out, so this looks like an issue with my machine/VS/Azure's emulator.

Add try-catch block in Activity function.

I could run your code by enclosing activity function with try-catch block and able to hit the exception in catch block of Orchestrator function.
Modified sample code:
public static class Function1
{
    [Function(nameof(Function1))]
    public static async Task RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        var logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(context.Name);
        var uploadRequest = context.GetInput<UploadRequest>();

        try
        {
            await context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(ResumeUpload), uploadRequest);
        }
        catch (TaskFailedException ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex, "inspect task failure exception");
        }
    }

    [Function(nameof(ResumeUpload))]
    public static async Task ResumeUpload([ActivityTrigger] UploadRequest uploadRequest, FunctionContext context,ILogger logger)
    {
      
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
        }
        catch (TaskFailedException ex)
        {
            logger.LogError("inspect activity task failure exceptions");
        }
    }

    [Function("Function1_HttpStart")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseData> UploadRequest(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
        [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
        FunctionContext executionContext)
    {
        ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Function1_HttpStart");

        string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
            nameof(Function1));

        logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);
        return await client.CreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(req, instanceId);
    }

Able to hit the breakpoint at the exception catch block.


Output:


Functions:

        Function1_HttpStart: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7070/api/Function1_HttpStart

        Function1: orchestrationTrigger

        ResumeUpload: activityTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-11-07T07:17:44.908Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='(null)', Id=53e3689e-e412-4ac5-ac5a-2f48651e7c4a)
[2024-11-07T07:17:49.162Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-11-07T07:18:05.470Z] inspect task failure exception
[2024-11-07T07:18:05.471Z] Result: inspect task failure exception
Exception: Microsoft.DurableTask.TaskFailedException: Task 'ResumeUpload' (#0) failed with an unhandled exception: Exception while executing function: Functions.ResumeUpload
[2024-11-07T07:18:05.473Z]  ---> DurableTask.Core.Exceptions.TaskFailedException: Exception of type 'DurableTask.Core.Exceptions.TaskFailedException' was thrown.
[2024-11-07T07:18:05.475Z]    at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.ScheduleTaskInternal(String name, String version, String taskList, Type resultType, Object[] parameters) in /_/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationContext.cs:line 121
[2024-11-07T07:18:05.477Z]    at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.ScheduleTaskToWorker[TResult](String name, String version, String taskList, Object[] parameters) in /_/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationContext.cs:line 92
[2024-11-07T07:18:05.478Z]    at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.ScheduleTask[TResult](String name, String version, Object[] parameters) in /_/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationContext.cs:line 84
[2024-11-07T07:18:05.480Z]    at Microsoft.DurableTask.Worker.Shims.TaskOrchestrationContextWrapper.CallActivityAsync[T](TaskName name, Object input, TaskOptions options)
[2024-11-07T07:18:05.481Z]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2024-11-07T07:18:05.483Z]    at Microsoft.DurableTask.Worker.Shims.TaskOrchestrationContextWrapper.CallActivityAsync[T](TaskName name, Object input, TaskOptions options)
[2024-11-07T07:18:05.484Z]    at FunctionApp1.Function1.RunOrchestrator(TaskOrchestrationContext context) in C:\Users\uname\Source\Repos\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\Function1.cs:line 19
Stack:    at Microsoft.DurableTask.Worker.Shims.TaskOrchestrationContextWrapper.CallActivityAsync[T](TaskName name, Object input, TaskOptions options)
[2024-11-07T07:18:05.488Z]    at FunctionApp1.Function1.RunOrchestrator(TaskOrchestrationContext context) in C:\Users\uname\Source\Repos\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\Function1.cs:line 19.
[2024-11-07T07:18:11.197Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='(null)', Id=3797fe6c-3f4c-4561-b9e5-5093c44bea9d)
[2024-11-07T07:18:24.414Z] inspect task failure exception
[2024-11-07T07:18:24.416Z] Result: inspect task failure exception
Exception: Microsoft.DurableTask.TaskFailedException: Task 'ResumeUpload' (#0) failed with an unhandled exception: Exception while executing function: Functions.ResumeUpload
[2024-11-07T07:18:24.419Z]  ---> DurableTask.Core.Exceptions.TaskFailedException: Exception of type 'DurableTask.Core.Exceptions.TaskFailedException' was thrown.
[2024-11-07T07:18:24.421Z]    at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.ScheduleTaskInternal(String name, String version, String taskList, Type resultType, Object[] parameters) in /_/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationContext.cs:line 121
[2024-11-07T07:18:24.423Z]    at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.ScheduleTaskToWorker[TResult](String name, String version, String taskList, Object[] parameters) in /_/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationContext.cs:line 92
[2024-11-07T07:18:24.425Z]    at DurableTask.Core.TaskOrchestrationContext.ScheduleTask[TResult](String name, String version, Object[] parameters) in /_/src/DurableTask.Core/TaskOrchestrationContext.cs:line 84
[2024-11-07T07:18:24.427Z]    at Microsoft.DurableTask.Worker.Shims.TaskOrchestrationContextWrapper.CallActivityAsync[T](TaskName name, Object input, TaskOptions options)
[2024-11-07T07:18:24.429Z]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2024-11-07T07:18:24.432Z]    at Microsoft.DurableTask.Worker.Shims.TaskOrchestrationContextWrapper.CallActivityAsync[T](TaskName name, Object input, TaskOptions options)
[2024-11-07T07:18:24.434Z]    at FunctionApp1.Function1.RunOrchestrator(TaskOrchestrationContext context) in C:\Users\uname\Source\Repos\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\Function1.cs:line 19
Stack:    at Microsoft.DurableTask.Worker.Shims.TaskOrchestrationContextWrapper.CallActivityAsync[T](TaskName name, Object input, TaskOptions options)
[2024-11-07T07:18:24.436Z]    at FunctionApp1.Function1.RunOrchestrator(TaskOrchestrationContext context) in C:\Users\uname\Source\Repos\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\Function1.cs:line 19.
[2024-11-07T07:18:44.910Z] Timeout value of 00:01:00 exceeded by function 'Functions.Function1' (Id: '53e3689e-e412-4ac5-ac5a-2f48651e7c4a'). Initiating cancellation.
[2024-11-07T07:18:44.952Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Failed, Id=53e3689e-e412-4ac5-ac5a-2f48651e7c4a, Duration=60078ms)
[2024-11-07T07:18:44.953Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Timeout value of 00:01:00 was exceeded by function: Functions.Function1.
[2024-11-07T07:18:46.988Z] A function timeout has occurred. Restarting worker process executing invocationId '53e3689e-e412-4ac5-ac5a-2f48651e7c4a'.
[2024-11-07T07:18:47.270Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 3888) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-11-07T07:18:50.624Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=3797fe6c-3f4c-4561-b9e5-5093c44bea9d, Duration=39430ms)


Thanks Pravallika, appreciate you taking the time to test. If this is working for you then it looks like there may be an issue specifically on my machine, because dotnet.exe just dies at the log line Worker (PID: 3888) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach... and I'm dumped back into VS with no debug session.
Does it also crash for you if you have no try/catch inside the activity?

I've got timeout error as you got without try/catch block

Thanks, so it's definitely a problem with my setup :(
Appreciate your help mate!

Did you try by adding try/catch block in activity function?

Yes, the process still died as before with the following message on the debug console: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe (process 15932) exited with code -1.

Run the same code in some other IDE or cli using command func host start.
